# Drawing Solid Lines on 3D Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am trying to draw a line moving along with a 3D graph to represent the region of integration.

[image]

So for this, the black line on the bottom represents the cut off for the region of integration. I would like to have a trace of the line moving along the surface of the function. Here is the MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
zmax=15,
zmin=0,
view = {45}{45},
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(Tan), color=(Tan)},
xlabel = $s$,
ylabel = $h$,
zlabel = {$f(s,h)$},
ticks = none,
]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=30,
domain=0:1.5,
opacity=0.5,
]
{12*exp(-(4*x+3*y))};

\draw[black, thick] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0);

\addplot3 [name path = xline, draw = none, domain=0:1.5] (x,0,0);
\addplot3 [name path = xcurve, domain=0:1.5, y domain = 0:0, draw = none] 
    (x, 0, {12*exp(-(4*x))});
\addplot [color = Tan, opacity = 0.5, draw = none]
  fill between[of = xcurve and xline];

\addplot3[
mesh,
draw=Bittersweet,
samples=30,
domain=0:1.5,
opacity = 0.75
]
{12*exp(-(4*x+3*y))};

% Attempt 1
%\addplot3 [domain=0:1.5, black, thick, samples=30] (x,x,{12*exp(-(4*x+3*y))});

%Attempt 2
%\addplot3 [domain=0:1.5, black, thick, samples=30] (x,x,{12*exp(-(7*x))});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The two commented out lines toward the end, which I called Attempt 1 and Attempt 2, are namely my two attempts at doing this. Here is the result for each of them:

**Attempt 1**

[image]

**Attempt 2**

[image]

Attempt 1 is a mess, but Attempt 2 is very close to what I want, but it draws a line across the start and end points of the function. Any suggestions as to how I could fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already were on the right track. You can achieve what you want by adding `samples y=1` to your second attempt.

(Besides that I did some minor optimazations to your code. See the comments in the code for details.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.16,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        zmax=15,
        zmin=0,
        view={45}{45},
        grid=minor,
        colormap={mycol}{color=(Tan), color=(Tan)},
        xlabel=$s$,
        ylabel=$h$,
        zlabel={$f(s,h)$},
        ticks=none,
        % (moved common options here)
        domain=0:1.5,
        samples=30,
    ]

        \addplot3[
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            % removed one `\addplot' by adding the next line
            faceted color=Bittersweet,
        ] {12*exp(-(4*x+3*y))};

        \draw [black, thick] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0);

        \addplot3 [
            name path=xline,
            draw=none,
        ] (x,0,0);
        \addplot3 [
            name path=xcurve,
            % replaced this ...
%            y domain=0:0,
            % by ...
            samples y=1,
            draw=none,
        ] (x,0,{12*exp(-(4*x))});
        \addplot [color=Tan, opacity=0.5]
            fill between [of=xcurve and xline];


        % Attempt 2
        \addplot3 [
            black,
            thick,
            samples y=1,        % <-- added
        ] (x,x,{12*exp(-7*x)});

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: +1: What is the meaning of `samples y=0`?

Comment: Interesting, I also would like to know why this works, thank you!

Comment: Using `samples y` is used for mesh plots and by default is set to the same value as `samples`. Setting it to `0` forces a line plot which is what you want to draw.

Comment: Addition: I just read in the [manual (section 4.6.2 on page 123 in v1.16)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=123) that also `samples y=1` or `y domain=0:0` forces a line plot. But the given examples all use `samples y=0`. I'll take a note and discuss with Christian to harmonize it.

Comment: It seems I missed to *send* this comment ...: I updated my answer using `samples=1` which was agreed on to use in the manual in future uniformly. It makes more sense to use *one* y sample instead of *none* ;)